# Permanent Alternative Monitor Resolution

Tags: display, tv, display-resolution

I was able to change the resolution of my htpc when plugged into my using the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139073/how-to-add-higher-video-resolution-in-ubuntu-10-04-unr-on-eee1101ha) quoted below.

How do I make this permanent?  Each time I log out I have to run the below again.

```
lexu@eee1101:~$ cvt 1366 768 60
1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync >+vsync

lexu@eee1101:~$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

lexu@eee1101:~$ xrandr --addmode "default" "1368x768_60.00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr, you can add this section to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or create the file with

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA1"
    Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1368x768_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "VGA1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1368x768_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

You have to change the line *Driver* to your correct graphic driver i.e. nvidia, fglrx, whatever.

Comment: Works with some modifications to "Monitor" and "Driver".  Thanks